Load script to Objection on startup
I tried to use objection (Frida tool) and I want to load a JavaScript script in startup
I run it objection -g com.myapp  explore but when I got prompt (to use import function` the application already running, that too late
So for know I use
frida  -U  -l myScript.js -f com.myapp
exit
frida-ps -Uai
objection -g PID explore 

Is there any way to use only objection to load script on startup ?

You can use the -S flag to do so:
objection -g PID explore -S myScript.js

Alternatively you can also build objection from source (release is about 3 years behind source):
https://github.com/sensepost/objection/wiki/Development-Environment-Installation
The commands are somewhat different though, such as using start instead of explore. However this setup it will allow you to use the -s flag to spawn the process when working with frida-server.
Using it as follows you can execute commands before running resume to continue the application execution:
objection -s -n "com.myapp" start
evaluate test.js
resume

Note: use evaluate in new version as import will throw an exception.

-S, --serial TEXT        A device serial to connect to.` is not java script that loaded before the spawn

@python3.789 The parameters are position dependent as they are per command.
I.e. objection -S <serial> explore is used to specify a device serial, while objection explore -S <filename> is used to specify startup script.
Be sure to check objection explore --help.
